# How to render a border to a div without occupying any extra space?

Tags: css

How can I apply a border to a div without occupying any extra space? The border must be inside the div.

Comment: I use the box-shadow technique instead,it's rendered inside.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You have 3 choices:

1. Inner and outer boxes(as @xpapad stated).
2. Using `outline`, e.g., `outline:1px #000 solid;`. [Read more](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp).
3. Using `box-sizing`, which is a css3 property. E.g., `box-sizing:border-box;`. [Read more](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

Comment: plus one for outline,was using border like border:solid black; still it was occupying the space.

Comment: @Justcode to note, outline is like decor, not a physical border. It overlaps anything in a z-index below it. and it doesnt have dimensions, only width and height pretty much :P

Comment: @TaylorS I agree. but it doesn't occupy space. that is what I wanted

Comment: Thanks. I need it from long time ago.

Comment: `outline` doesn't have separate properties for sides, like i.e. `border-right` does.

Comment: box-sizing not working for me, border still makes the button bigger

Comment: box-sizing will only influence the width and height as it relates to the parent, but borders will still reduce the available space inside even with box-sizing on. Outline is likely your solution @SuperUberDuper

Answer (score 17):

you can compensate it with negative margin, or simply use outline.

```
div { border: 10px solid red; margin: -10px};
```

or

```
div { outline: 10px solid red; }
```

alternatively you could use css3 boxshadow to fake a border...

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/K23s7/

Comment: I was using the `outline` prop, but not working with the `border-radius` on Safari.

Answer (score 7):

Try using a negative margin equivalent to your border, eg.

```css
border-right: 1px;
margin-right: -1px;
```

Comment: Good option for rounded borders without changing the size of the image.

Answer (score 3):

For my use case, the box-shadow property was the right choice.

More precisely, box-shadow with 0 blur and a bit of spread.

The "border" it creates is not inside the div, but it doesn't occupy extra HTML space.

```css
button {
    background: white;
    font-size:2rem;
    padding:1rem 2rem;
    color: #4f93df;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    margin:1rem;
}

.withABorder{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px #4f93df;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Hello</button>
  <button class="withABorder">World</button>
  <br>
  <button>Hello Again</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Include an inner div inside your current div, using the required border.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add a border using `box-shadow`, like this:

```css
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red; /* Border bottom */
box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 red; /* Border top */
box-shadow: -1px 0 0 0 red; /* Border left */
box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 red; /* Border right */
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red; /* All the borders by using the spread properties */
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else...my issue was with a toggle bar that displays a border when you hover over it. I solved it by just adding a transparent border when not hovering:

```
.toggle-bar {
    text-align: center;
    background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow;
    border: 2px solid lightgoldenrodyellow;
    width:100%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size:x-large; 
}

div.toggle-bar:hover {
    border: 2px dashed blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```