# keep HTML floating elements in place when size changed

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have no idea how to keep the elements in place.
When I hover over a floating element, the border is adjusted but this pushes the other elements around (the images are 300x300px). How can I keep them in place? Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>These are images</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

The style.css file is:

```
.imgDiv {
float:left;
border: 1px solid black;
text-align:center;
border-radius:10px;
margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
} 
.img {
border-radius:10px;
} 
.imgDiv:hover {
border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: A possible answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625812/css-hover-border-makes-inline-elements-adjust-slightly

Comment: I think the **Title** of my post is more **relevant** than the title of the above-mentioned thread.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce margin while hover to keep DIVs position.

```css
.imgDiv {
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.img {
  border-radius:10px;
} 
.imgDiv:hover {
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>These are images</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="imgDiv">
            <img class="img"/>
            <h3>Click on image!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

add this line to .imgDive:hover

```
margin: -4px 6px 10px -4px !important;
```